# Play Mp3 from after saving it locally on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to play an mp3 song which first will be downloaded locally and then it will be played.

I have written following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[songURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLResponse *response;        
NSError *error;
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *pathForSoundFile  = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/my.mp3"]];
NSLog(@"%@",pathForSoundFile);

NSURL *myURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pathForSoundFile]];

[self  playPreviewMethod];

-(void)playPreviewMethod
{
    [songPreview play];
}
```

What I guess is that the file is not downloaded or converted in the mp3 format.

Comment: Where do you start downloading ?I do not see any code starting the file's download...

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[songURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLResponse *response;        
NSError *error;
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];                                                                                              songURL => This variable contains the URL of song

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your file getting downloaded?

Check out the folder `Library-> applicationSupport-> iPhone Simulator -> your folder-> Documents`

Chck out whether the file is downloaded. and if the file is getting downloaded then check out the name of the file whether it is my.mp3 or not. I think theres the problem you are not passing correct name while playing the file.

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: @Suriya.Yes The file  was getting downloaded by the name of my.mp3 but its size was very small. But Now I directly passing the URL to play the song, not storing it locally. It is working fine. Thanks for your reply :-)